# How to make checkboxes work in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I am currently creating a form that lets the user choose a certain skills from a Dropdown and a Checkbox for hobbies that lets the user check as much he/she wants.

Here is my Table for that:  `CurriculumVitae`

```
/* namespace ........... */

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* CurriculumVitae
*
* @ORM\Table(name="foo_cv")
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class CurriculumVitae
{
    /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @var integer
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Skills")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="skills", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    private $skills;

    /**
    * @var integer
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Hobby", cascade={"persist"})
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="hobbies", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    private $hobby;

    /*  Setters and Getters   .......  */
}
```

Here are some codes for my Form Type:  `CurriculumVitaeType`

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $builder
        ->add('skills', 'entity', array('class' =>'FooBarBundle:Skills','property' => 'skills'))
        ->add('hobby', 'entity', array( 'class' => 'FooBarBundle:Hobby','property' => 'hobbies', 'expanded'=>true,'multiple'=>true, 'label' => 'hobbies'))
        ->add('save','submit',array('label'=>'Submit'))
    ;
}

/* OptionsResolverInterface  .....   */
/* getName()  .... */
```

I call my form in my twig this way in:  `cv.twig.html`

```
{{ form(curriculumForm) }}
```

And lastly in my controller:  CurriculumController

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$cv = new CurriculumVitae();
$curriculumForm = $this->createForm(new CurriculumVitaeType(), $cv);
$curriculumForm->handleRequest($request);

if ($curriculumForm->isValid()) {
    $em->persist($cv);
    $em->flush();
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('foo_main_window'));
}
return array('curriculumForm'=> $curriculumForm->createView());
```

The Form Displays correctly but when I choose a skill from the dropdown and assign a certain hobby and click on submit, an error is thrown.

> Found entity of type Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection on association Foo\BarBundle\Entity\CurriculumVitae#hobby, but expecting Foo\BarBundle\Entity\Hobby

I dont know if i missed something but i think the error occurs in the process of persisting the data after the form is submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have many-to-one relation, which means

> **Many** `CurriculumVitae`s can have (the same) **single** `Hobby`

But on the other hand you've created in your form a field with option `'multiple'=>true`, which means that you let the user to choose multiple hobbies. Therefore form returns `ArrayCollection` of `Hobby` entites instead of single instance.

That doesn't match. You need to either remove `multiple` option, or make many-to-many relation on `$hobby` property.

Comment: Should I also include a constructor in my CurriculumVitae Entity?

    /**
    * Constructor.
    */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->hobby = new ArrayCollection();
    }

Comment: **if** it's a collection, then yes. But I don't know what is your expected result, so I can't suggest which way you should go.

Comment: My main goal is to pick a single skill from the dropdown and assign hobbies to them. :)

Comment: If so, you need to make many-to-many relation instead of many-to-one.

Comment: The ManyToMany Relationship really worked.. thanks a lot :)